# Can't enter device in lost mode: device location for all apps is turned off, and you may not be able to locate your device if it is lost

Tags: android-management-api

Device is android version 12 and is fully managed. The "start_lost_mode" command is processed fine but when entering alert state the message just automatically closes without any input. Additional message pops about location being turned off.

The expected behavior is that alert state will be active for at least 5 minutes as stated in docs.

- I gave Device Policy app all permissions available including access to location at all times. Plus made sure location is on at the time of request.
- Also tried to enforce location mode.
  Even though the location is on before request arrives, at the time of request it automatically switches off. Then alert state closes and "apps can't access location" message pops. Really confused about what can be the reason for all that.